# SQL2K5 Standard to Enterprise upgrade

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have SQL2K5 Standard configured in an active/passive W2K8 cluster in my Production environment, and on a standalone box in my Staging environment. I want to upgrade to SQL2K5 Enterprise (mostly for the parallel indexing capability). I need to do this with minimal downtime (failover hiccoughs are fine). Following is a high-level WBS and my question:

1. upgrade Staging and smoke test
2. configure a spare production grade server with SQL2K5 Standard and script manual Production cutover to this box should it become necessary
3. backup Production db
4. fail over Prod to DB2 (passive Prod db server)
5. install Enterprise on DB1 (active Prod db server)
6. verify & validate installation
7. fail back to primary
8. install Enterprise on DB2
9. V&V installation
10. test failover and fail back

My question is this: am I asking for trouble by not pulling the whole cluster offline? For a time during this procedure, I will have multiple editions of SQL2K5 under the W2K8 cluster manager. I don't know if this is an issue, but it gives me a Bad Feeling. I believe setting up the standby SQL2K5 Standard as a swing target should the installation hit a snag mitigates this risk sufficiently, but I would be grateful for feedback.

Thanks!

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to build a new clean temporary cluster using spare and staging server to reduce risks.

You can't upgrade just one node, if I recall correctly, because SQL Server does a cluster install not a node install. So, steps 4-8 won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server 2005 installer does not allow you to upgrade a passive SQL Server node, which i think is what your suggesting.  The database server will be offline for the duration of the upgrade, as GBN has indicated. you cannot do steps 4 to8.

Are you suggesting creating a new named instance of SQL 2005 ENT in the existing cluster in a side-by-side fashion?  is this what you mean by:

> I will have multiple editions of SQL2K5 under the W2K8 cluster
>   manager

If so then this isn't really an 'upgrade' & you'll still have to deal with moving databases, logins, agent jobs ect. across to the new instance.